# JSON create, insert and select query

Tags: json, sql-server, nosql, key-value-store

I am trying to create a key/value table which fetches the instructor name and salary over 80000. I am not able to make a SELECT statement here. using Json here.

```
CREATE TABLE instructortest (
 ID  INT PRIMARY KEY,
 info VARCHAR(max) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE instructortest
ADD CONSTRAINT "valid JSON"
CHECK (ISJSON (info) = 1);

INSERT INTO instructortest 
VALUES (78699,'{"name":"Pingr","Department":"Statistics","salary":"59303.62"}' )

select JSON_VALUE(info, '$.name') from instructortest 
where ('$.salary') = 59303.62
```

Comment: added key-value-store

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use JSON_VALUE again in your where clause:

```
select JSON_VALUE(info, '$.name') from instructortest 
where cast(JSON_VALUE(info, '$.salary') as decimal(18,2)) > 80000
```

Comment: And what if i want to find a value > 80000....select JSON_VALUE(info, '$.name') from instructortest 
where JSON_VALUE(info,'$.salary') > 100000  (it gives me error Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '59303.62' to data type int.)   where clause with > is having problem

Comment: when you inserted the json data, there were quotes around the number, which means it's going to treat it as a string. so for any numeric comparisons, it's going to be trying to do some automatic type conversions. I think there are a couple reasons why your original example does work and the `> 80000` doesn't, but the clearest thing to do would be to explicitly cast the json value, so it's clear what data type it should use. so update your where clause to `where cast(JSON_VALUE(info, '$.salary') as decimal(18,2)) > 80000`